Failed to install matplotlib X86
I can not install matplotlib on Python 3.11 X86. I get an error message:
error: Failed to download any of the following: ['https://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/freetype/freetype2/2.6.1/freetype-2.6.1.tar.gz', 
 'https://download.savannah.gnu.org/releases/freetype/freetype-2.6.1.tar.gz', 
 'https://download.savannah.gnu.org/releases/freetype/freetype-old/freetype-2.6.1.tar.gz'].  
Please download one of these urls and extract it into 'build/' at the top-level of the source repository.
  [end of output]  

Note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
ERROR: Failed building wheel for matplotlib
ERROR: Could not build wheels for matplotlib, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

pip install matplotlib

No conda please

python -m pip install matplotlib

It looks like someone was running into a similar problem here: Error trying to install matplotlib in Windows
Have you tried using the --pre flag like this: pip install matplotlib --pre
It looks like it may possibly be the case that the current latest version of matplotlib does not support python3.10 and that may be what is causing the issue.

This one is for X64. I need it for X86.

@KuChow do you need this because of an x86 version (32 bit) version of python? Are you sure you can't use a different version of python to get this to work? If not, I think you have to try and look for a version of matplotlib that works with 32 bit python here: https://pypi.org/project/matplotlib/3.5.0/#history and install them like this: pip install matplotlib==3.5.0

Yes, I need X86 because of the program software uses X86.

Same error message
build\lib.win32-cpython-311\matplotlib\mpl-data\fonts\pdfcorefonts
running build_ext
error: Failed to download any of the following: ['https://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/freetype/freetype2/2.6.1/freetype-2.6.1.tar.gz', 'https://download.savannah.gnu.org/releases/freetype/freetype-2.6.1.tar.gz', 'https://download.savannah.gnu.org/releases/freetype/freetype-old/freetype-2.6.1.tar.gz'].  Please download one of these urls and extract it into 'build/' at the top-level of the source repository.
